# Skydrive - Authorization grant flow returning Microsoft account error

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, onedrive

I am using the sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243649.aspx#authorization

Specifically, my code looks like:

```
wb1.Navigated += wb1_Navigated;
string tokreq = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=<my client id>&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com";
wb1.Navigate(tokreq);
```

The redirect to google is just a placeholder since I don't have a web site as of now, wb1 is a webbrowser control in a WPF desktop application.

[image]

The service status says that Skydrive is running fine, and infact all Microsoft services are in green status https://status.live.com/ , so I guess I am breaking something in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two obvious reasons why it would not work;

- You didn't use a valid client id in the request.
- Your redirect URL is not *exactly* the same as the redirect URL that is registered on the client ID in the [account.live.com site](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/).

If neither of these solve your problem, paste your exact URL into a browser and look at the *URL* (not the page) you're redirected to, it will contain detailed error info.

Comment: Yup, it was the 2nd one. Didnt realise it had to match exactly